# How to train a language model (like BERT, or any other) to not classify a sentence in a particular class?

Tags: natural-language, transformers

I have limited data, around 50 sentences per class and around 70 classes. Due to this reason of having less data, sometimes some sentences get classified in a class, which are similar but not belonging to that class.

Is there any architecture or method by which I can further fine-tune the model to not classify a sentence in a particular class?

Or is there some better approach for such a classification problem with less data?

For more details:
The classification problem is to classify legal clauses (which can be sentences or paragraphs) into one of 70 classes (like Confidentiality clause, Governing Law clause, Termination clause, etc.)
My current approach is to fine-tune Legal-Bert to perform this classification task. The problem is limited data - around 50 training samples per clause.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your model is not perfect but you want a perfect model? Do you expect your model not to misclassify any test instances?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PascalIv I do not want a perfect model. I want to know, if I can further train the model where it misclassifies, particularly for false positives? And if so how?